# Transparent to white in Imagick for PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I have a png image with a transparent background and I want to convert it to a jpg image with a white background.

The code is basically this:

```
$image = new Imagick('transparent.png');
$image->writeImage('opaque.jpg');
```

But that creates a black background jpg. I've been struggling with the worst documentation ever trying to find a way to convert the transparent to white to no avail.

**Edit**:
Well, I tried Marc B's idea and kind of got it to work.

```
$image = new Imagick('transparent.png');
$white = new Imagick();

$white->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), "white");
$white->compositeimage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$white->writeImage('opaque.jpg');

$image->destroy();
$white->destroy();
```

The problem now is, it always causes the script to segfault.

Comment: Try doing the `destroy()` calls in the opposite order; first `$white`, then `$image`.  `$white` might be hanging onto a pointer to `$image` because of the composition, then trying to refer to it during `destroy()` and segfaulting because it's gone away.

Comment: @chaos Unfortunately, it's not that. I'm having such a bad experience with this library.

Comment: Yeah, APIs to ImageMagick are kind of notoriously like that.  I've been known to give up on native code and just write `system()` calls to `convert` on the command line.

Comment: It's almost funny how ridiculous the documentation on the PHP Imagick API is.

Answer (score 19):

`flattenImages()` actually works.

But keep in mind that it doesn't modify the given `\Imagick()` object *but returns a new one*:

```
$image = new \Imagick('transparent.png');

// Need to use the result of $image->flattenImages() here!
$image = $image->flattenImages();
$image->writeImage('opaque.jpg');
```

`flattenImages()` defaults to the background color `white`. If you want to use another background color you have to set it *before* loading the image:

```
$image = new \Imagick();

// Needs to be called before the image is loaded!
$image->setbackgroundcolor('green');
$image->readimage('transparent.png');

$image = $image->flattenImages();
$image->writeImage('opaque.jpg');
```

In general the Imagick API is *very* sensible when it comes to the order of function calls (just like `convert` and its parameters on the command line) so always check if your order is correct.

Good luck!

*Edit April 2016:*

`$image->flattenImages()` [was deprecated](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/deprecate.php#MagickFlattenImages) and should be replaced by:

```
$image->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN)
```

It's hard to find exact informations about this, but it seems that this applies to PHP >= 5.6.

Thanks to vee for the tip!

Comment: This explains what is actually going on.

Comment: the result of the flattenImages() worked for me. thanks

Comment: Now, flattenImages() is deprecated. use $image->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN) instead.

Comment: This worked for me but I first forgot to reassign the `$image` variable with the result of `flattenImages()`.

Comment: If you want to reassign the `$image`, you can use `setImage()` method: `$image->setImage($image->mergeImageLayers(Image::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));`

Comment: Does PHP (or imagemagick?) do so some sort of auto detection when it comes to setting transparent background color when re-saving a PNG to JPG if setImageBackgroundColor is not explicitly called? I came across some PNG images where doing a simple conversion to JPG leads to some part of the background being black with color streaks in them, while the rest of the background turns white.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
$image = new Imagick('transparent.png');
$image->setImageMatte(true);
$image->setImageMatteColor('white');
$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE);
$image->writeImage('opaque.jpg');
```

Comment: copy/paste the image on top of a white image of the same size? bit more work/overhead, but should work.

Comment: @Marc B's idea seems like it should work if my last attempt doesn't.  (Should write that as an answer, Marc B. :)

Comment: Just a random thought. chaos has done a lot more work on this than I have. he deserves the credit.

Comment: @Marc B: I don't really agree.  Actually solving the problem counts for more than effort. :)

Comment: @Marc B: I tried that and it does convert the image properly, but it causes the script to segfault. Description updated with the new code.

Comment: Since you're not doing anything fancy, just pasting one image onto another, there are the GD functions which could do the trick. I haven't used Imagick at all in PHP as GD usually met my needs.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem when converting PDFs to PNGs, and I used flattenImages().

```
        //get the first page of the PDF
        $im = new imagick( $file.'[0]' );

        //set the background to white
        $im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');

        //flatten the image
        $im = $im->flattenImages(); 

        //do the rest of the image operations
        $im->setResolution( 181, 181 );
        $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
        $im->resizeImage ( 181, 181,  imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, TRUE);
        $im->setImageFormat('png');
        $imageName = $title.'_thumb.png';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$image = new Imagick('transparent.pdf');
$image->setImageType (imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR);
$image->writeImage('opaque.tif');
```

did for me!

(instead of the formerly imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLORMATTE)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked to me with PDF to JPG conversion

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$white->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), "transparent");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by changing Imagick constant as shown below

```
//$image will conatains image which needs background to be transparent
$white = new Imagick();

$white->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), new ImagickPixel( "white" ));
$white->compositeimage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x1OfTransparentImage, $y1OfTransparentImage,);
$white->flattenImages();
$white->writeImage('opaque.jpg');    

$white->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it works for me:

```
$im = new Imagick('trans.png');
$im->setimagebackgroundcolor('white');
$im = $im->flattenimages();

$im->writeimage('transToWhite.jpg');
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue with segfault I ran into the same issue.
Apparently `$image->writeImage('somename')` destroys `$image` or the reference to it.

I was running into the same issue. The way I got around it was by removing the call to destroy on the object that I had finished writing. Seems sloppy but that solved the issue with the segfault

Answer (score 0):

**Segfault issue:**
I had a similar problem (script kept giving me segfault, even when the image was properly processed and written), the solution I found came after checking bug reports, see:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61122

Knowing that, try adding
    `$white->setResourceLimit(6, 1); // 6 means "limit threads to"`
before the problematic line (in my case I had to put it before $im->resizeImage(...);)

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I was trying to replace transparent background with white (but keep as png).  Tried several different methods (including setImageAlphaChannel with setImageBackgroundColor).  Combining OP's use of compositeImage I came up with this (hopefully helpful to someone else):

```
$pic = new Imagick($filelocation); //specify file name
$pic->setResourceLimit(6, 1);
if ($pic->getImageAlphaChannel()) {
    $white = new Imagick();
    $white->newImage($pic->getImageWidth(), $pic->getImageHeight(), "white");
    $white->compositeImage($pic, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
    $pic = clone $white;
    $white->destroy();
    $pic->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
}
//do more things with $pic
```