# View pdf file in browser instead of downloading

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize ('theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf' ) ); 
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment;     
filename=".basename('theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$filepath = readfile('theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf');
```

Hi friends i've code of this type. my requirement is i've to display the loaded pdf(open the pdf in browser) in browser but where as now the pdf is downloaded to hard disk . instead I would like to view the file in browser .

Comment: are you using dompdf

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal  No I'm not using it

Comment: use inline instead of attatchment

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal yup given and its working thanks a lot guys

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal could you pls tell me how to convert this loaded PDF into a image

Comment: You can use ImageMagick to Convert PDF to low resolution JPG file.       refer below links          http://stackoverflow.com/q/21935436/3021429                                              http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-pdf-to-jpeg-in-php_498.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to change the `Content-disposition` to `inline`.

Change

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment;     
filename=".basename('theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf'));
```

To:

```
header("Content-disposition: inline;     
filename=".basename('theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloading or Opening of a PDF file depends on setting in the browser.

Browser Setting to Open the PDF File instead of download:

Open PDFs in Chrome
On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More Settings.
At the bottom, click Advanced.
Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
Near the bottom, click PDF documents.
Turn off Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome.

Setting in Mozilla Firefox

1. Click on Extreme Right 3 lines.
2. Click on Options
3. In General Selection go to Applications
4. Set for PDF File as "Preview in Firefox"