# Forcing a PDF to Open in Browser Rather Than Downloading using FPDF Class of PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

I have tried this, still unable to get the preview of it in browser. But the file is downloaded automatically which is not desired.

```
$pdf->Output('I','EstimateReport.pdf');
```

Comment: Update your question and add  your html related  code  .. of your php code complete with the html for the page

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891513/view-pdf-file-in-browser-instead-of-downloading

Comment: Remove the parameters from your call to the Output method.

Comment: Can you use the network inspector in your browser to see what headers are being sent?  You may need to set the Content-Disposition manually: header("Content-disposition: inline; filename='EstimateReport.pdf'"));

Maybe also try removing the filename parameter.

Are you able to view a PDF from a different source in this same browser?